# Outlook timezone issues with an ics file. File loads OK in google calendar, MacOS etc

Tags: time, outlook, timezone, icalendar

Loading this file in Outlook shows the event starting at 1:30 AM PT instead of 0:30 AM PT (and 9:30 AM BST instead of 8:30 AM BST). Loading it in Google Calendar loads the times as intended.

Here are the correct times according to timeanddate.com: https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/converted.html?iso=20171019T0830&p1=136&p2=137&p3=0

Any idea what could be the reason for this?

The file is produced by icalendar 2.0 (a ruby gem) -- I'll be happy to provide the code for that, too.

`BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:icalendar-ruby
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Europe/London
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:19711031T020000
TZOFFSETFROM:+0100
TZOFFSETTO:+0000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=10
TZNAME:GMT
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:19681027T000000
TZOFFSETFROM:+0100
TZOFFSETTO:+0100
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=10
TZNAME:BST
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20170720T004211Z
UID:72e941fa-eb92-4740-b0b2-50cab1d6c536
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/London:20171019T083000
DTEND;TZID=Europe/London:20171019T190000
DESCRIPTION:Event description
LOCATION:London\, United Kingdom
SUMMARY:London ics test
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR`

EDIT:

I fixed a bug in my code which was causing a null starting date before setting the timezone. The resulting ics file is below:

Am I understanding correctly the meaning of the VTIMEZONE dates?

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:icalendar-ruby
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Europe/London
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:20170326T020000    <-- daylight savings start for THIS event's dates
TZOFFSETFROM:+0000
TZOFFSETTO:+0100
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=3
TZNAME:BST
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD             
DTSTART:20171029T010000   <-- daylight savings end for THIS event's dates
TZOFFSETFROM:+0100
TZOFFSETTO:+0000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=10
TZNAME:GMT
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20170720T171429Z
UID:5cfa170a-9df1-4a05-a2e1-050888f48e4b
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/London:20171019T083000  <-- TZID ignored by outlook but used by apple and google calendars... I presume they have daytime savings info built in?
DTEND;TZID=Europe/London:20171019T190000     -- Outlook takes the date part and calculates offset based on the timezone section?
DESCRIPTION:Event description
LOCATION:London\, United Kingdom
SUMMARY:London ics test
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where did you get this VTIMEZONE definition ? It is totally bogus: both DAYLIGHT and STANDARD switchover are in October and the TZOFFSETFROM/TZOFFSETTO have the same value in the case of STANDARD.

Unlike other clients which do ignore the VTIMEZONE and just rely on the TZID if it is known to them, Outlook does care (also because it does not use the same TZID values).

Try with something like:

```
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Europe/London
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
TZOFFSETFROM:+0000
TZOFFSETTO:+0100
TZNAME:BST
DTSTART:19700329T010000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=-1SU
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZOFFSETFROM:+0100
TZOFFSETTO:+0000
TZNAME:GMT
DTSTART:19701025T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=10;BYDAY=-1SU
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
```

Comment: @amaudq, thank you. I found a bug in my code where I was passing a nil starting date prior to assigning the timezone. Could you point me to a resource where I can find about the structure of timezone definitions and their relationship with the event start and end dates? Am I correct to presume that Outlook takes the timezone definition (incl. daytime savings start and end), and calculates the current offset for the event dates? I have edited my question with an updated ICS content.

Comment: You should not try to craft the VTIMEZONE info yourself. There is zero relationship between the event start/enddate and the vtimezone definition. The VTIMEZONE content is driven by local regulation. Your ruby gem probably comes with a set of predefined VTIMEZONE definitions and that is what you should be using if you have to deal with multiple timezones. Did you try with the one I provided you with ?

Comment: You should not have to worry about that but since you asked: Those timezones are for most of them generated from https://www.iana.org/time-zones and then translated in the VTIMEZONE format described at https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5545#section-3.6.5

Comment: Arnaudq, I fixed my code and now the ruby gem provides an ics which loads the correct time in Outlook as well the rest of the calendar clients. At this point I'm trying to understand the mechanics/interpretation of vtimezone in the definition. The icalendar gem uses the tzinfo gem for comprehensive up to date timezone information. Seen in the second part of the timezones section. https://github.com/icalendar/icalendar/blob/master/README.md#timezones